# Packing and unpacking function data when occasionally returning multiple values in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am reading a log and trying to process thousands of blocks of text (packets) sent as `file_object` to the function. The aim of the function is to help create a dictionary where the frame number (`FN`) is the key and all relevant data across different log packets is dropped into the frame key (Frame numbers can match across different blocks/packets). The packet type IDs remain the same throughout the log, just the content is changing.

So in the function, the block of text (packet) arriving is multi-line, so I split on a new line at the start of the function. The arriving packet is in two different formats shown below, the packets containing the `'='` separator were working fine in the function as there is only one frame `FN` in each block.

The problem I am having is the second block, where I have several frames and frame information in one packet, so I am trying to split and grab each frame data from the second text block and return it to the main script.

Once back in the main script a match is made on frame number and the data from the function is dropped into the dictionary. As mentioned, this is fine when there is one frame number, but with multiple frame numbers arriving back into the main script the key matching has a problem.

Here's the first packet, this works fine as there is only one frame number...

```
1980Jan6 Time 03:24:05.373 001111  Packet type1
Type             = 1
FN               = 230
Active           = Yes
```

And here's the second packet with several frames (FN)

```
1980Jan6 Time 03:24:05.373 001222  Packet type2
| FN  | Flag type | Size | Is Set |
| 230 | 4a        |  30  | TRUE   |    
| 231 | 64        |  20  | TRUE   |    
| 232 | Test      |  28  | FALSE  |    
| 233 | Not set   |   8  | FALSE  |
```

I am creating a dictionary for each frame number and dropping the relevant matching frame number properties.

```
u'230': {'Type': u'1',
         'FN': u'230',
         'Active': u'Yes',
         'Flag Type': u'4a',
         'Size': u'30',
         'Is Set': u'TRUE'},
```

My problem is after processing the other frame numbers in the second packet as I need to return multiple properties to the main script and save to a dictionary

Here's a snippet from the main script section sending the data to the function (`f` is the log set earlier in the script):

```
packets = {}
parser.open_log(f)

mypkt = parser.app.packet

while (mypkt.next()):
    data = process_data_direct(mypkt.text) # Here we go off to the function with the packet
    packets[data['FN']] = data # here we process the returning function data
```

I made an attempt along the lines of `for item in data:` in the above section of the main script, but to no avail.

Here's the function:

```
def process_data_direct(file_object):
    split_data = file_object.split('\n')

    frame1 = {}
    frame2 = {}
    frame3 = {}
    frame4 = {}
    framelist = [frame1,frame2,frame3,frame4]
    frame_no = 0    

    for line in split_data:
    if '=' in line:
        key, value = line.split('=', 1)
        frame1[key.strip()] = value.strip()

    elif re.search(r'\|\s+\d+\|', line):
        frame_no += 1
        metric = [x.strip() for x in line.split('|')] 
        if int(metric[1]) > 0:
            framelist[frame_no]['FN'] = metric[1]
            framelist[frame_no]['Flag Type'] = metric[2]
            framelist[frame_no]['Size'] = metric[3]
            framelist[frame_no]['Is Set'] = metric[4]

    return (frame1,frame2,frame3,frame4)
```

I think the function is packing the data correctly, but the main script is struggling to make sense of the arriving data.

Comment: Why not have two frame-parsing functions, and select the appropriate one for each frame based on whether the first line ends with `'type1'` or `'type2'`?

Comment: Hi jonrsharpe, I guess this makes sense, I was hoping to keep everything tidy in one function.  How would I go about unpacking the data in the main script if I am returning up to 4 frame blocks each with a 'FN' property (return (frame1,frame2,frame3,frame4))  if I created a separate function at this point in the main script... packets[data['FN']] = data   ?

Comment: Well firstly I wouldn't limit it to four frames, just iterate over the lines until you run out. Secondly, the function that parses multi-frame packets should return a list of frames that you can then iterate over to pack each individual frame into your overall dictionary.